# Heliocentric Positions

Tags: python, skyfield

Is there a way to calculate heliocentric planetary coordinates (longitude and latitude) with Brandon Rhodes' python program, Skyfield?

If I only do:

`mercury(utc=(1980, 1, 1)).ecliptic_latlon()`

I get a Barycentric object, and therefore the latitude and longitude don't match heliocentric values.

I tried:
`sun(utc=(1980, 1, 1)).observe(jupiter)`
but that raises errors:

```
skyfield/relativity.py:128: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in true_divide
ehat = pe / emag
skyfield/relativity.py:144: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in double_scalars
fac1 = 2.0 * GS / (C * C * emag * AU_M * rmass)
```

Using Python 3.4, skyfield `0.4, de423`

Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried? Did you read the docs? Did you try coding it? Please read stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @xml I've edited the question as suggested. As to the docs, Skyfield is one of those very neatly written programs where the best documentation is the code itself.  I suspect what I'm after has to do with the positionlib.py module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Python 3.4 and Skyfield 0.4, I am able to run:

```
from skyfield.api import sun, jupiter
p = sun(utc=(1980, 1, 1)).observe(jupiter)
lat, lon, d = p.ecliptic_latlon()
print(lat)
print(lon)
```

and get the result:

```
01deg 00' 46.7"
+151deg 19' 21.7"
```

I wonder what is making the equation cited return a divide-by-zero in your case? Your approach was correct, by the way — heliocentric positions are measured from the Sun, not from the middle of the Solar System, so you were doing exactly the right thing!

If you could add a `print` statement to the Skyfield source code right above the line that errors, it would be interesting to see which of those values in the denominator becomes zero for you!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks very much Brandon. Equipped with your answer I quickly found what the problem was: instead of just creating an Astrometric object with:
`sun(utc=(1980, 1, 1)).observe(jupiter)`
I followed with attempting to create an Apparent object:
`astrometric = sun(utc=(1980, 1, 1)).observe(jupiter)
apparent = astrometric.apparent()`
And that is what created the error.

1) This left me with a quandry, though:
The longitude and latitude values obtained are:
+151deg 19' 21.7"
01deg 00' 46.7"
I checked with the online site for JPL Horizon and they get about exactly the same values.
However, in a (privately written, Java) program I use, also based on the SPiCES JPL files, the value obtained for the heliocentric longitude is: 
151deg 02' 
Searching for heliocentric ephemerides online, I immediately came across one (http://www.astro.com/swisseph/ahel/1900/ahel1980.pdf) which also indicates +151deg 02'.
Any idea why two sets of values?

2) Is stackoverflow the right place to ask these questions, BTW?

Thanks again!